# Table lines in beamer dropped when more than one slide present in presentation

Tags: tables, beamer

I have a presentation that has drops the lines separating cells in a table under  specific conditions, when it previously compiled without problems.

MWE:

```
%%% Local Variables:
%%% mode: pdflatex
%%% TeX-master: t
%%% End:


\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[norsk]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen}


\mode<presentation>
{
 \usetheme{Frankfurt}
  \setbeamercovered{transparent}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Bevegelighetstrening (forts.)}
\begin{block}{Anbefalinger for bevegelighetstrening}
\begin{itemize}
 \item 10-30 sek.
\item Fire ganger per muskelgruppe
\item To til tre ganger i uken
\end{itemize}
\end{block}
\end{frame}
\note[itemize]
{
\item 4 x 30 s + pause = ca. 5 min hver øvelser
}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Oppsummering}
\begin{tabular}{>{\columncolor{black}\color{white}\bfseries}m{1.4cm}m{4.2cm}|m{4.2cm}|}
\rowcolor{black}
\color{white}\bfseries  & \color{white}\bfseries \scriptsize     Helsefremmende Anbefalinger    & \color{white} \bfseries \scriptsize ACSM Anbefalinger\\\hline
\scriptsize Målgruppe       & \color{black}\scriptsize Rettet mot alle              & \color{black}\scriptsize Begrenset til friske voksne personer \\\hline
\scriptsize Intensitet      & \color{black}\scriptsize Både middels og intensiv         & \color{black}\scriptsize Intensiteten for de fleste er høyere enn middles\\
                            & \color{black}\scriptsize Økt intensitet gir økt gevinst               & \color{black}\scriptsize Må være av en viss intensitet for at effekten blir optimal \\\hline 
\scriptsize Varighet        & \color{black}\scriptsize Tid i aktivitet kan samles opp       & \color{black}\scriptsize Tid i aktivitet kan samles opp\\ 
                            & \color{black}\scriptsize Hver økt ikke bør være kortere en ti min & \color{black}\scriptsize Hver økt ikke bør være kortere en ti min\\
            & \color{black}\scriptsize Avhengig av treningsintensitet       & \color{black}\scriptsize Lavere frekvens skyldes at kroppen trenger tid til å hente seg inn mellom økter\\\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{frame}
\note[itemize]
{
\item Oppsummering av forskjellene mellom anbefalingene
}

\end{document}
```

If I remove the preceding frame/slide the lines in the table show no problems and the lines show if I hide the notes.

This occurs when compiling with pdflatex or xetex.

Is this a bug in beamer or am I missing something? I am using the latest version of beamer; v3.36.

Comment: I think i can see all lines. Try zooming in and out of your document, readers somethimes have trouble with deciding what to do.

Comment: @Johannes_B I tried zooming in and out but it it had no effect. What is strange now is that it is working after I renamed the file and moved it to another directory!? There must have be a problem with either the name of the file or something in the directory the tex file was located...Thanks for the input at least :-)

Comment: Can you show a before/after screenshot sowe definitely are talking about the same lines?

Comment: Ah, so there isn't an reproducable issue and we can close this question?

Comment: In short; yes :-).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue mysteriously was resolved and isn't reproducable. Please see the comment above.